# How to get return value from renderHook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I got a custom hook which return a function

```
export function useMyCustomHook = (dispatch) => () => {... some things with dispatching to store };
```

I'm trying to use the return value like this in a jest test:

```
  const result = renderHook(() => useMyCustomHook(useDispatch()));
  console.log(result.current);
```

but `result.current` is undefined. So how can I actually get the return value?

Comment: what are you returning from your hook?

Comment: @AmitChauhan The hook is there. I'm returning a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to react-hooks-testing-library `renderHook` returns an object with result, so to access it:

```
const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyCustomHook(useDispatch()));
console.log(result.current);
```

Comment: Now if you want to try and look at a follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476912/testing-custom-hook-invariant-violation-could-not-find-react-redux-context-val