# Testing custom hook: Invariant Violation: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I got a custom hook which I want to test. It receives a redux store dispatch function and returns a function. In order to get the result I'm trying to do:

```
const { result } = renderHook(() => { useSaveAuthenticationDataToStorages(useDispatch())});
```

However, I get an error:

> Invariant Violation: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a

It happens because of the `useDispatch` and that there is no store connected. However, I don't have any component here to wrap with a provider.. I just need to test the hook which is simply saving data to a store.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The react hooks testing library [docs](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks) go more into depth on this. However, what we essentially are missing is the provider which we can obtain by creating a wrapper. First we declare a component which will be our provider:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

const ReduxProvider = ({ children, reduxStore }) => (
  <Provider store={reduxStore}>{children}</Provider>
)
```

then in our test we call

```
test("...", () => {
  const store = configureStore();
  const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <ReduxProvider reduxStore={store}>{children}</ReduxProvider>
  );
  const { result } = renderHook(() => {
    useSaveAuthenticationDataToStorages(useDispatch());
  }, { wrapper });
  // ... Rest of the logic
});
```

Comment: Note that if you put this `ReduxProvider` in it's own file (as I did), you need to import react for it to work `import React from 'react';`

Comment: what is `configureStore()` ?

Comment: [`configureStore()`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configurestore/) is a helper from redux-toolkit that that adds good defaults to the store setup for a better development experience. `import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";` It's not necessary to use `configureStore` to test custom hooks, though.

Comment: PS  an empty store didn't work for me based on my custom hook. I had to initialize my store like so to get my test to work `const store = configureStore( reducer: <my reducers here>});`

Answer (score 16):

This is probably a late answer but you can also use this in your test

```
jest.mock('react-redux', () => {
    const ActualReactRedux = jest.requireActual('react-redux');
    return {
        ...ActualReactRedux,
        useSelector: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return mockState;
        }),
    };
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. I added this to a test, but I still see the error about missing a `<Provider>`. Could you expand this answer?

Comment: Consider provide the full answer.

Comment: I get an error `TypeError: require.requireActual is not a function`, do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Sachihiro you need `jest.requireActual` not `require.requireActual`

Comment: Seems it works but you won't be able to update the mockState in test cases?

Comment: Docs say you should recreate the store for each test, not mock it. Prob not correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

This issues is related your test file. You have to declarer **provider** and **store** in your test file.

Update or replace your `app.test.tsx` by below code

NB: Don't forget to install `redux-mock-store` if you don't have already.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

import App from './App';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

describe('With React Testing Library', () => {
    const initialState = { output: 10 };
    const mockStore = configureStore();
    let store;

    it('Shows "Hello world!"', () => {
        store = mockStore(initialState);
        const { getByText } = render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App />
            </Provider>
        );

        expect(getByText('Hello World!')).not.toBeNull();
    });
});
```

I got this solution after searching 1 hours.
Thanks a lot to [OSTE](https://github.com/oste)

Original Solution: [Github issues/8145 and solution link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8145#issuecomment-515821572)

---

With this solution if you get error like **TypeError: window.matchMedia is not a function** then solve by this way. add those line to your `setupTests.ts` file. Original solution link [stackoverflow.com/a/64872224/5404861](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64872224/5404861)

```
global.matchMedia = global.matchMedia || function () {
  return {
    addListener: jest.fn(),
    removeListener: jest.fn(),
  };
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can create `test-utils.[j|t]s(?x)`, or `whatever you set the name of the file to`, like this:

`https://github.com/hafidzamr/nextjs-ts-redux-toolkit-quickstart/blob/main/__tests__/test-utils.tsx`

```
//root(or wherever your the file)/test-utils.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { render, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

// Import your store
import { store } from '@/store';

const Wrapper: React.FC = ({ children }) => <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;

const customRender = (ui: React.ReactElement, options?: Omit<RenderOptions, 'wrapper'>) => render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...options });

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react';
// override render method
export { customRender as render };
```

Use it like this:
 `https://github.com/hafidzamr/nextjs-ts-redux-toolkit-quickstart/blob/main/__tests__/pages/index.test.tsx`

```
//__tests__/pages/index.test.tsx


import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '../test-utils';
import Home from '@/pages/index';

describe('Home Pages', () => {
  test('Should be render', () => {
    render(<Home />);
    const getAText = screen.getByTestId('welcome');
    expect(getAText).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Works for me.

[screenshot work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t51s.png)

BTW, if you place the `test-utils.[j|t]s(?x)` or `whatever you set the name file` place on the directory `__test__`, don't forget to ignore it on `jest.config.js`.

```
//jest.config.js

testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/.next/', '<rootDir>/__tests__/test-utils.tsx'],
```

repo: https://github.com/hafidzamr/nextjs-ts-redux-toolkit-quickstart

Comment: works for me. tks.