# Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test my **antd** application with **react testing library**, but I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined

Im using a custom render but the error seems to be coming from the 'render' method.

> const customRender = (ui, options) =>
> render(ui, { wrapper: TestingWrapper, ...options })   ^

I´m even using the same versions of react and react-dom (which seems to be a common issue with rtl).

> "react": "17.0.1",
> "react-dom": "17.0.1",

The problematic component seems to be this:

```
import React, {
  lazy,
  Suspense
} from 'react';

import List from 'antd/lib/list';
  
const Stories = (props) => {
    return(
  <div className="stories-container">

    <div>
      <h1 className="StoriesTitle">Stories</h1>
    </div>

    <div className="StoryListContainer">
     <Suspense fallback={<Spin />}>
        <List
          itemLayout="vertical"
          size="default"
          pagination={pagination}
          dataSource={stories}
          renderItem={item =>
            <StoryItem
              item={item}
              deleteFn={onDelete}
              loggedIn={loggedIn}
              stories={stories}
            />
          }
        />
      </Suspense>
    </div>

  </div>
    );
}
```

It seems to error out in the module 'antd/lib/_util/responsiveObserve' which is a part of antd's List component. Taking that component out makes the test work (though obviously I don't want to remove it from my application).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Are you perhaps using defining `window.matchMedia` in your jest `setupTest.js` file? What fixed it for me is to move it from `window.matchMedia` to `global.matchMedia` like how they did it in [this repo](https://github.com/AO19/typeError-cannot-read-property-addListener-of-undefined/commit/873ce9b730a1c21b40c9264e5f29fc2df436136b).

```js
global.matchMedia = global.matchMedia || function () {
  return {
    addListener: jest.fn(),
    removeListener: jest.fn(),
  };
};
```

Comment: Yup, that seems to have done the trick. I also have matches: false on that return statement, but I don't know wether it made a difference or not.

Answer (score 14):

Try the below code, which works for me.

```js
  delete window.matchMedia
  window.matchMedia = (query) => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
  })
```

Comment: This works for me, however the `delete window.matchMedia` is redundant, as you're overriding it on the next line anyway

Comment: This was it for me, when the accepted answer and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830580/jest-test-fails-typeerror-window-matchmedia-is-not-a-function wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that during the tests `document` does not exist. You can use a library like jsdom:
https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom

Comment: I'm running my application inside CRA ( https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/ ) JSDOM is included by default (in fact, running the test with --env=node yields a different error - "Document not defined" - and makes another test in the suite fail), so I'm reasonably confident that jsdom is not the problem. 

It seems to error out in the module 'antd/lib/_util/responsiveObserve' which is a part of antds List component. Taking that component out makes the test work (though obviously I don't want to remove it from my application).